# Make API requests on a remote server from Postman

Tags: postman

I work on a remote server via ssh, I ran a service locally on the remote server but how can I hit API's from my local machine's Postman to the service API's on remote server.

I am able to make curl requests from the remote server but I am not able to do the ssh tunneling in Postman, what are the steps I should follow?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

While both ssh and HTTP are protocols to communicate between client and server. The basic difference between SSH and HTTP;

I guess you know, but just for others/clarification - SSH means “Secure Shell”. It has a built-in username/password authentication system to establish a connection. Thing is, **it uses Port 22** to perform the negotiation or authentication process for connection. Authentication of the remote system is done by providing a public-key from your machine.

The default Port for most Web-Servers to listen for requests is either **Port 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS**

#### To make it work

You can either expose a Port on your remote server by defining a firewall rule (even though 80 should probably be open) and make your server listen to incoming requests on that Port.

#### OR

**Now, if you wan't to making it publicly available**
put both, your remote Server and your local machine in the same VPN Network - still your server needs to listen for HTTP requests on some Port.

If you are not using some kind of reverse proxy, make sure to specify the port you are contacting the server on e.g. `http://localhost:8080`